# Using safe non-const function in a const function

Tags: c++, eigen, const-correctness

I need to use `MatrixSequence::matrix` in my stream operator `ostream& operator<<(ostream &outputStream, const MatrixSequence &sequence)`, so I need it to be const. However it uses `Map<Matrix>` which doesn't seems to be const safe. I got the error

```
matrixsequence.cpp:38: error: invalid conversion from 'const double*' to 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >::PointerArgType {aka double*}' [-fpermissive]
```

when I add the final const keywrk to `MatrixSequence::Matrix`

```
typedef Eigen::MatrixXd Matrix;
typedef Eigen::Map Map;

Map<Matrix> MatrixSequence::matrix(const unsigned int i) const {
    assert(i <= shapes_->size());
    const double* beginning = &data_.at(beginning_matrix->at(i));
    const tuple<int, int>& shape = shapes_->at(i);
    return Map<Matrix>(beginning, get<0>(shape), get<1>(shape));
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &outputStream,
                    const MatrixSequence &sequence) {
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<sequence.size(); i++) {
        outputStream << "\n" << sequence.matrix(i) << "\n";
    }
    return outputStream;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eigen, but it looks like it might work if you change the return type to `Map<const Matrix>`.

Comment: Eigen::Map<const Matrix> doesn't work. I get errors on unrelated parts of the code. I think it is because their is a lot of template metaprogramming in Map<>.

Comment: That's a shame. If `Map` really isn't const-correct, then there's probably no way you can make your code const-correct either; you'll just have to either drop your `const`, or use `const_cast` and hope for the best.

Comment: Eigen::Map<const Matrix>  should really work. Which Eigen version are you using?

Comment: I use the version 3.2.0. The minimal code is here https://gist.github.com/MatthieuBizien/7936480 I think it is because beginning have to be non constant for Map<>(beginning, ...).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, a cleaner solution is to return a `Map<const MatrixXd>` as in the self-contained example:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
using namespace Eigen;

struct Foo {
  double data[10];

  Eigen::Map<const MatrixXd> foo() const {
    Map<const MatrixXd> out(data, 5, 2);
    return out;
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  MatrixXd A = 2 * f.foo();;
}
```